# Linq Ternary in where clause to fall through to all records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table of workorders that have a boolean field of `IsActive` (ie workorders can be deactivated). In my repository, you can request active workorders, or inactive workorders, or all workorders. I have created an enum to encapsulate these 3 states, as I will use the same approach on other tables as well.

My current Linq query is as follows:

```
ActiveInactiveEnum activeInactive = ActiveInactiveEnum.Active; // or .Inactive or .All
var workOrders = _db.WorkOrders
                   .Where(i => activeInactive == ActiveInactiveEnum.Active ? i.IsActive.Value : activeInactive == ActiveInactiveEnum.Inactive? !i.IsActive.Value : true)
                   .Select(i => new workOrderViewModel{
                       Id = i.Id,
                       Title = i.Title
                   });
```

This appears to work as desired, but I'm not sure about the `true` in the last ternary part of the where clause. Resharper wants me to "Simplify conditional ternary expression" as follows:

```
.Where(i => activeInactive == ActiveInactiveEnum.Active ? i.IsActive.Value : activeInactive != ActiveInactiveEnum.Inactive || !i.IsActive.Value)
```

But this doesn't return all records when the enum value is `.All`.

Is there a simpler or better way to represent my query, especially one that Resharper will like? Is the use of `true` in the where clause here correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The ReSharper code results in the same logic. Are you saying you get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your code and the resharper code will return `true` when `activeInactive == ActiveInactiveEnum.All`, but you stated that:

> But [the ReSharper code] doesn't return all records when the enum value is `.All`.

Looking at the logic, however, it seems that it must. We start with:

```
activeInactive == ActiveInactiveEnum.Active 
    ? i.IsActive.Value 
    : activeInactive != ActiveInactiveEnum.Inactive || !i.IsActive.Value
```

So, when `activeInactive == ActiveInactiveEnum.All`, then the condition evaluates to `false`, and we end up looking only at the second return value:

```
activeInactive != ActiveInactiveEnum.Inactive || !i.IsActive.Value
```

Here we have `(true || <some value>)`, which, just like your logic, will return `true`.

Comment: THank you for writing it out that way, as it looks clearer to me. I have reexamined, and I must have made a mistake previously; you're absolutely right that it evaluates to true when .All. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would find either solution (before and after Resharper recommendation) harder to read and maintain, than something like this:

```
var query = _db.WorkOrders.AsQueryable();
if(activeInactive != ActiveInactiveEnum.All)
     query = query.Where(i => i.IsActive.Value == (activeInactive == ActiveInactiveenum.Active));
var workOrders = query.Select(i => new workOrderViewModel{
                       Id = i.Id,
                       Title = i.Title
                   });
```

Comment: I agree. The only problem with that is that there are additional where clauses (kept out for clarity), so they would have to be repeated in the `if` statements.

Comment: Additional where clauses that only occur based on the IsActive value? If not, then there should be no issue in adding them either before or after the if block has modified the query.

Comment: No, they're based on other values.